# Sorting dates array in Asc & Desc order Partially incorrect logic-Protractor

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, protractor

I need to sort a given array of dates in DD-MMMM-YYYY format in ascending & descending array through a Javascript function & Assert this result with a static defined array. Below is the code i tried but seems like its partially working:

```
it("Sorting DD-MMMM-YYYY Arrays",function(){
    var unsorted_array1=['25-Nov-2005','04-Aug-2015','04-Aug-2015','30-Jun-2006','26-Jun-2013','27-Jun-2013','15-Feb-2001','10-Jul-2012','29-May-2012'];
    var unsorted_array2=['25-Nov-2005','04-Aug-2015','04-Aug-2015','30-Jun-2006','26-Jun-2013','27-Jun-2013','15-Feb-2001','10-Jul-2012','29-May-2012'];

    var arraytobecompared_desc=['04-Aug-2015','04-Aug-2015','27-Jun-2013','26-Jun-2013','10-Jul-2012','29-May-2012','30-Jun-2006','25-Nov-2005','15-Feb-2001'];
    var arraytobecompared_asc=['15-Feb-2001','25-Nov-2005','30-Jun-2006','29-May-2012','10-Jul-2012','26-Jun-2013','27-Jun-2013','04-Aug-2015','04-Aug-2015'];


    var sorted_with_function_ascending= unsorted_array1.sort(function(a, b){
        var aa = a.split('-').reverse().join(),
        bb = b.split('-').reverse().join();
        return aa < bb ? -1 : (aa > bb ? 1 : 0);
    });

    var sorted_with_function_descending= unsorted_array2.sort(function(a, b){
        a = a.split('-');
        b = b.split('-');
        return b[2] - a[2] || b[1] - a[1] || b[0] - b[0];
    });


    console.log("Ascending dates- "+sorted_with_function_ascending);
    console.log("Descending dates- "+sorted_with_function_descending);  

    expect(arraytobecompared_desc).toEqual(sorted_with_function_descending);
    expect(arraytobecompared_asc).toEqual(sorted_with_function_ascending);

    })
```

both the ascending & Descending functions are returning the inbetween values sort incorrect which is causing the expect block to fail.

Comment: That's probably because `Aug` is alphabetically before `Jun`. You should use months numbers instead of names

Comment: I cannot modify the dates format. Could you suggest any modification inside the function itself to handle this ?

Comment: Yes, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what I came up with :

```js
let unsorted_array = ['25-Nov-2005','05-Aug-2015','04-Aug-2015','30-Jun-2006','26-Jun-2013','27-Jun-2013','15-Feb-2001','10-Jul-2012','29-May-2012']

var sortable = [];
unsorted_array.forEach(date => {
    sortable.push([ date, new Date(date).getTime() ]);
})

sortable.sort( (a, b)  => a[1] - b[1] )

let sorted_array = sortable.map(arr => arr[0])

console.log(sorted_array)
```

I'm building an array containing :

```
[
   ["date", "corresponding timestamp"],
   ["date", "corresponding timestamp"]
]
```

Then I sort the array by timestamp`( (a, b)  => a[1] - b[1] )`

then I extract every first element with map `(arr => arr[0])`

The output is :

```
["15-Feb-2001", "25-Nov-2005", "30-Jun-2006", "29-May-2012", "10-Jul-2012", "26-Jun-2013", "27-Jun-2013", "04-Aug-2015", "05-Aug-2015"]
```

For descending order, replace `a[1] - b[1]` with `b[1] - a[1]`.